# Jquery UI slider with opposite values?

Tags: jquery, slider, increment, decrement

First of all, I'm jquery starter, so please don't get mad on my lack of knowledge.

I'm trying to build a jquery slider which has it's switch on exact half of its width, and two inputs with values from slider which works in specific way:

If you move slider's switch to the left side, value in `#first` input gets decremented and value in `#second` gets incremented. For right side it's reversed situation.. So If I move slider to right and `#second` box gets (for example) value 30, `#first` gets value 70.

I hope you understand my need..

Till now I've managed to get switch in middle of slider and `#first` inputs gets value from slider

I don't know how to move on from here

You can see and edit situation here: http://jsfiddle.net/M8AWg/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="first"/>
    <input type="text" id="second"/>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#first, #second').val('50');

$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider(
    { value: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#first" ).val( ui.value );
            $(ui.value).val($('#first').val());
            }     
        }
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the total always 100? If so you can just add this line:

```
$( "#second" ).val( 100 - ui.value );
```

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/M8AWg/1/

Comment: yea man, that's it.... love you :)... I will accept your value as soon as I can :), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the value from the slider and minus 100 to get your remainder.
also `$(ui.value)` would be looking for `$(30)` which doesn't exist

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider(
    { value: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#first" ).val( ui.value );
            $('#second').val(100-ui.value);
            }     
        }
    );
  });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8AWg/2/)